# django rest framework filter ignores int field that is mapped to enum

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have what I hope is a simple query for the stack overflow community.

Given the following configuration, I have a fairly simple int field on my "Totals" model and can't seem to get filtering to work on that field.

**Here is the object from models.py:**

```
class TotalType(Enum):
    daily_sum = 1
    weekly_sum = 2

class Total(models.Model):

    TOTAL_TYPES = (
        (TotalType.daily_sum, 'Daily Sum'),
        (TotalType.weekly_sum, 'Weekly Sum')
    )

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, db_column='LocationId')
    ci_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ci_TimeStamp', blank=False, null=False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
    total_type = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, blank=False, choices=TOTAL_TYPES)
```

**Here is the router info from urls.py:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'totals', TotalViewSet)    
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
)
```

**Here is my object serializer:**

```
class TotalSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name="location-detail", many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Total
        fields = ('id', 'location', 'ci_timestamp', 'amount', 'total_type')
```

**Finally, here is the view configuration:**

```
class TotalViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):        
    filter_fields = ('total_type', 'location')    
    queryset = Total.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TotalSerializer
```

**The problem:**

1. A request for all "totals" works fine: GET /totals returns all.
2. A request for "totals" by location works fine: GET /totals?location=1 returns all totals for location 1.
3. A request for totals by total_type returns 0 results, incorrectly: GET /totals?total_type=1 returns 0 results. No error thrown.

Looking at the debug toolbar, I can see that no query is executed using the Total model. It makes the queries against django_Session and auth_user and that is it. These queries return as expected.

If I call with both params (location and total_type), I can see that it makes the query with only the location in the WHERE clause, but the API still returns no results...even the the query does (although erroneously).

Any ideas??

Django 1.6.4
Python 2.7
djangorestframework 2.3.13

Comment: upvoted the question as even just the question helped me see how to use this feature properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer (which struck me 2 minutes after I posted the question):

I needed to use the enum values in my choices, not the actual objects that represent the name/value pairs.

Like this:

```
TOTAL_TYPES = (
    (TotalType.daily_sum.value, 'Daily Sum'),
    (TotalType.weekly_sum.value, 'Weekly Sum')
)
```

I'm surprised that everything else worked except for the REST filtering params before I made this change.